# How to avoid a name collision between a boolean and a method which returns it

Tags: c++, naming, name-collision

Let's say that I've got a class which handles animations. Inside of this class is a boolean called `isLooped` and a function which returns this boolean. My question is, what can I do to avoid calling the function and variable the same thing?

I have thought about adding a prefix to my class variables, but that would mean making changes across my entire code base, which I don't desire.

Comment: Does the function and the member have the same access control?

Comment: What is the actual name of the function returing the "isLooped" field ? I'm not sure to understand correctly the question but basically the answer to "what can I do to avoid calling the function and variable the same thing?" is just : give them two different names

Comment: They don't have the same access control.

Comment: Have a different naming convention for member functions and member variables.

Comment: I was going to call the function "isLooped" as well, because that's how I usually call functions which return booleans. I can obiviously call it something else, but it wouldn't be consistent with my style.

Comment: Then rename the boolean to `is_looped` or something. There are no solutions but to rename one of the two.

Comment: Isn't this completely a matter of opinion? Anyways, some like `mIsLooped` as member variable, some like `isLooped_`, some like to give it completely different names.

Comment: Personally, I would call the Boolean `looped` and the method `is_looped` (or `isLooped` if you're attached to the camel case convention). But that's me.

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely a matter of naming conventions, here are two trivial options:

**Option #1**
You could for example use UpperCamelCase for method names, and LowerCamelCase for member names.

```
class Object {
    bool IsLooped() { return isLooped; }
    bool isLooped;
}
```

**Option #2**
You could use LowerCamelCase for method names and member names, and use some kind of a prefix/suffix for member names, such as `m_`, or just `_`

```
class Object {
    bool isLooped() { return m_isLooped; }
    bool m_isLooped;
}
```

I prefer option number #2, since it makes life easier when trying to understand which objects are members.

Answer (score 0):

Forewarning I am not super aware of the popular conventions in C++.

I would keep `isLooped` the same and rename your method to `getIsLooped()`.  I think it makes the relationship quite clear.  If public `GetIsLooped()` is more appropriate.  But obviously the convention used in the rest of the code base is going to influence that decision.

Comment: GetIsLooped is awkward. It seems much more natural to ask to call the function IsLooped() and get an answer to the question.

Comment: One of my most hated conventions: putting `get` before everything. It doesn't even read correctly, would you rather `std::complex z{40, 2}; auto r = z.real();` or `auto r = z.GetReal();`. Talk about getting real.